# Can't change background-color of class "menu"

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, background-color

I want to change color of class "menu" but I don't know why when I call class "menu" on css like below, it doesn't change. Can you suggest me a better CSS reset, or any other solution?

```
.menu{
 background-color: black;}


<div class="menu">
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand offset-3 fixed-top">
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-menu">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id ="collapse-menu">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#gioithieu">ABOUT</a> 
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a> 
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT</a> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: share full code, you may have more CSS involved

Comment: background-color property probably already set on "containter" class or for nav. Check for that in your CSS.

Comment: It can not, because I have a lot of classes "container" below. I tried add id nested div but when I call this id on css, it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background is not displayed as the `.menu` collapses and has zero height and width. This happens because the child has a `position: fixed` and drops out of the parent thread. You can also use the Bootstrap 4 classes to define [background-color](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/#background-color).

```
<div class="menu fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand offset-3">
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-menu">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-menu">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#gioithieu">ABOUT</a> 
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a> 
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT</a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/jEbcp1KvQW

Answer (score 0):

try using !important like this

```
<style>
    .menu
    {
     background-color: black!important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Still can't change

Comment: the best thing you can do here is try to ctlrl + shift + i    click 'elements'  and search for the class="menu"  then check for the styles if there is some css overriding  yours. and remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<style>
.menu{
 background-color: black !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Still can't change.

Comment: Or try this if you want only navbar color to be changed

`.navbar {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
}`

Comment: PS: Add custom css after bootstrap css else it will override.

Comment: But class "navbar" nested class "container". I think it not useful.

Comment: Don't add nav into container.

Comment: I want to add this to gird system.

Comment: In this case you must try inline css in navbar with `!imporant`